# Question being closed as "off-topic"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am interested in understanding why [my recent question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83365/why-was-michelle-salzman-not-censured-by-florida-house-of-representatives) was closed as "off-topic". The close blurb thing states:

> answers would be based on speculation and their correctness could not
> be verified with sources available to the public

But this is true for thousands of politics stack exchange questions that are highly voted and remain open to this day. For example, consider the following questions:

[Why try to impeach Trump now?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/48387/why-try-to-impeach-trump-now)

[Why do soldiers not rebel in impoverished dictatorships?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/83464/why-do-soldiers-not-rebel-in-impoverished-dictatorships)

[Why does Mexico support Maduro?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/47746/why-does-mexico-support-maduro)

Take the first question ("why impeach Trump now?"). Without explicit statement from Democratic politicians, there is necessarily going to be an element of speculation. That doesn't mean that answers can't provide useful insight. The same applies to my question as well.

Can any mod (preferably the one who closed it) provide a better explanation why the question was closed? Failing that, can the question be reopened.

Comment: I haven't voted to close your Q, but based on the comments there, it was closed because the answer was too obvious, rather than speculative.

Comment: I guess you are referring to James K's comment. Obie 2.0's comment just below does a good job of explaining why the answer isn't obvious in the way that James'  claimed.

I have just realised that questions are not closed by mods, but by a voting system. In that case, I would like to request a mod to review the close, since I believe the voting was due to political bias and not in line with community guidelines.

Comment: Actually a diamond mod did vote to close your Q. His vote counted for 2x normal votes in this case. (There were 3 votes to close from regular users too, including James K.) Diamond mods can even single-handedly close or delete questions, regardless of score etc.

Comment: I am obviously unable to see that. Could the diamond mod please explain their reasoning?

Comment: You can probably see the list here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/83365/timeline#history_80b15809-b444-4a02-b368-1d8e65fa41a1

Comment: @Fizz, thanks a lot! I had no idea I could access that info and still have no idea how to access it. Is there a way I can contact those mods to find out more on why the question was closed? "not suitable for this site" tells me very little.

Answer (score 3):

> Why was Michelle Salzman not Censured by Florida House of Representatives?

There are no reports of a resolution to censure Salzman. There was a lot of talk about doing so, but no resolution.

> I am wondering what are the political forces at play that allow a call for the genocide of Palestinians to pass unremarked?

It is speculative to try to identify the "political forces at play", especially, when no resolution to censure has been submitted and there are no comments on why one has not been submitted.

More to the point, for the close reason, we have no way to determine the "internal motivations of people" — why those people didn't do something that you fully expected should have been done.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. Could you clarify how the the question differs from "Why try to impeach trump now?" (internal motivation of Democratic politicians) and "Why does Mexico support Maduro?" (internal motivation of Mexican leaders).